# Not using a return value of a method , Is it bad design?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

Following is an example code ,  `checkUserGuess` method that belongs to a `Board` class.

```
public String checkUserGuess(String aGuess)
{
   // Some processing

   return result_of_a_guess;
}
```

I have a `SimpleGuessingGame` class consumes this method and is satisfied with the processing that the method does. It does not use the returned value.

Another class `ComplexGuessingGame` consumes this method and also uses the value returned by the method for further processing.

So we have two cases , one where the return value is used and other where its ignored. Is this a common occurrence or does this point to bad design ?

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of a hypothetical example. If this is actual code, then show us what *some processing* actually does. As it stands, it looks like `checkUserGuess` is doing more work than it should be doing.

Comment: sometimes return values are needed sometimes not. what if i have a function insert(Object o) that inserts and returns the dateTime of when it was inserted. I might need to use it in one call or I might just ignore it

Comment: Not necessarily, Collections return the removed element when you delete it, it isn't bad designed

Comment: Is not a bad design unless you never use it. Sometimes this kind of compromise must be taken in order to not duplicate code...

Comment: This sounds like your method has a side effect. If that's the case, it's absolutely plausible to ignore the return value if it is of no interest to the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to do something like this, chances are that the method does two things that are of value to a caller:

1. Validates something, or produces another side effect, and
2. Computes the result to be returned to the callers

Since some users need only #1, while other users need both #1 and #2, it may be a good idea to split the method in two parts, like this:

```
public void validatekUserGuess(String aGuess) {
   // Some processing
}
public String checkUserGuess(String aGuess) {
    validatekUserGuess(aGuess);
   // Some additional processing
   return result_of_a_guess;
}
```

Now the users that wish to ignore the return value would not be required to "pay" with CPU and memory for computing a value that they are going to discard anyway.

Comment: Value may well be calculated while validating, so it essentially does two useful things. Computation may have to be repeated just to have a separation of concerns.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's certainly true. It's hard to guess what exactly is going on without seeing the actual code or knowing the exact purpose of the method, though.

Comment: @CKing I misunderstood the question, i thought it was 1 function doing the same thing, with another function doing again the same thing, but with a return

Comment: @BrandonLing CPU cycles are not as important as the clarity for the readers. The callers who do not need the computed result would call `void validatekUserGuess`, thus expressing their intentions in a more direct way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight my apologies, read my new comment. i misunderstood at first

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's why we have comments :) You can always ask the OP for clarifications before posting an answer.

Comment: @BrandonLing Please think before you type. You are saying things and taking them back. Then deleting comments. Then saying something else. Then taking it back.. you get my point. That being said, I agree with your view that calling `checkuserGuess` always will bring us back to square one.

Comment: @CKing I made one adjustment (misunderstood, deleted the comment, then posted the real comment about why his solution is wrong)

Comment: I agree partially with @BrandonLing. Maybe if he was computing the result of some complex data type he could break it down in this way, but for computing a String result? Seems a little overboard to try to save CPU cycles like that in what seems to be a simple game. Two functions would muddle readability more than just a comment that says `//only complexguessinggame uses this return value` or something to that effect.

Comment: @CKing Marko made a guess, suggesting that the code "does two useful things". I find this rather unlikely, yet not impossible, so I replied to him in a very polite way. This does not mean that I need any clarifications from the OP, or that I don't know why the site has comments.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I did not mean to be rude so I take the part about the comments back. But I still stick by my comment. When it comes to questions of this nature, it's a good idea to wait for the OP to provide more clarifications. This is also the reason why I have not downvoted the answer since the OP has not confirmed what the method does.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with using a return value in one call, and not using it in another.

Imagine in one case you want to *attempt* to turn a light on, and in another you want to make sure it was *actually* turned on.

```
public boolean turnOn(Light l);
```

case 1:

```
turnOn(new Light());
log.debug("Attempted to turn on light");
```

case 2:

```
boolean turnedOn = turnOn(new Light());
if (turnedOn) {
    log.debug("Light is turned on");
} else {
    log.debug("Not able to turn light on");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two are exactly identical (and the `result_of_a_guess` is *needed* but just not returned) then I would say that you are fine. Many times built-in functions have return values that people ignore because they just don't need them (but they are nice to have for extra processing, like you seem to be doing).

If you really don't like the return value then you can place `result_of_a_guess` in a member variable to be only set when the `checkUserGuess` is flagged as complex like so:

```
public void checkUserGuess(String aGuess, Boolean isComplex)
{
   // Some processing

   if (isComplex)
      setResult(result_of_a_guess)
}
```

I've seen a lot of both. In my opinion it comes down to a stylistic choice/ preference. You need to know and understand the scope of your project and what works best for you and your future code!